# Action bar not showing overflow menu

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

UPDATE: The problem is only in the xml view. On running the app it works just fine. Some error with the rendering in android studio i think.

Im watching a video tutorial in which the action bar shows the overflow menu by default. When i create a new project the overflow menu isnt visible even though menu_main.xml contains an item. i tried using different minimum SDK settings while creating the project and also tried different app themes but it didnt work. here is the code->

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shreyans.overflowmenu" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.shreyans.overflowmenu;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me a way to make the overflow menu visible?

Comment: What version of Android are you running the app on?

Comment: Min SDK is 15 and target is 22 I think. Where can I check?

Comment: No, I mean what version of Android is on the device or emulator that you are running the app on?

Comment: The overflow menu isnt visible in the xml design view itself. Also i ran it on Nexus 5 API 23 x86 and the overflow menu is visible now! should i delete the queston? why isnt it visible in the xml design view?

Comment: "why isnt it visible in the xml design view?" -- I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: ok this is off topic but how do i check the min-sdk and target-sdk as my AndroidManifest doesnt contain any <uses-sdk> tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90701/discussion-between-shreyans-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/i1"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/title_i1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/i2"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/title_i2"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/i3"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/title_i3"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/title_menu">
    <menu>
        <item
    android:id="@+id/i1"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/title_i1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/i2"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/title_i2"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/i3"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/title_i3"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```